# TFS - WorkItem validation error for 'Assigned To' field

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm trying to set the value of the 'Assigned To' field in TFS using C#. The value I am setting is "MYDOMAIN\\DOMAINID". Where:

- MYDOMAIN is the domain name and
- DOMAINID is the user name of a user

When I attempt to validate the item it fails with the reason 'InvalidListValue'.

However, when I try to set the same value in the same worktiem via a REST Patch call, it works.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here or how to rectify this error?

Edit: Here's the sample code:

```
using TF_Frmwrk_Client = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using TF_WIT_Client = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

public bool CreateTFSWorkItem()
{
    string fieldValue = String.Empty;
    TF_WIT_Client.FieldDefinition tfFieldDefinition;
    TF_WIT_Client.Field tfWorkItemField;

    TF_Frmwrk_Client.CatalogNode collectionNode = null;

    if (_collectionNodes != null)
    {
        collectionNode = _collectionNodes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Resource.DisplayName == "MyProjectCollection");
    }

    var tpcId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
    var tpc = _configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(tpcId);
    TF_WIT_Client.WorkItemStore wiStore = tpc.GetService<TF_WIT_Client.WorkItemStore>();

    var project = wiStore.Projects["MyTFSProject"];

    var tfWorkItemType = project.WorkItemTypes["Bug"];
    var tfWorkItem = new TF_WIT_Client.WorkItem(tfWorkItemType);

    // Field 'Title'
    tfFieldDefinition = tfWorkItemType.FieldDefinitions.TryGetByName("Title");
    if (tfFieldDefinition != null)
    {
        tfWorkItemField = tfWorkItem.Fields.GetById(tfFieldDefinition.Id);
        if (tfWorkItemField != null)
        {
            if (tfWorkItemField.IsEditable)
            {
                if (tfWorkItemField.Value != null)
                {
                    if (!tfWorkItemField.Value.Equals("This is a title!"))
                    {
                        tfWorkItemField.Value = "This is a title!";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("TFS field not found: FieldName '{0}'.", "Title"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("TFS field definition not found: FieldName '{0}'.", "Title"));
    }


    // Field 'Assigned To'
    tfFieldDefinition = tfWorkItemType.FieldDefinitions.TryGetByName("AssignedTo");
    if (tfFieldDefinition != null)
    {
        tfWorkItemField = tfWorkItem.Fields.GetById(tfFieldDefinition.Id);
        if (tfWorkItemField != null)
        {
            if (tfWorkItemField.IsEditable)
            {
                if (tfWorkItemField.Value != null)
                {
                    if (!tfWorkItemField.Value.Equals("MYDOMAIN\\MYUSER"))
                    {
                        tfWorkItemField.Value = "MYDOMAIN\\MYUSER";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("TFS field not found: FieldName '{0}'.", "Assigned To"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("TFS field definition not found: FieldName '{0}'.", "Assigned To"));
    }

    string valiationMessage = string.Empty;
    ArrayList invalidFields = tfWorkItem.Validate();

    if (invalidFields.Count > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder fieldErrors = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (TF_WIT_Client.Field field in invalidFields)
        {
            fieldErrors.AppendFormat("Field: \"<b>{0}</b>\", Value: \"<b>{1}</b>\", Validation failure reason: <b>{2}</b>.<br />",
                field.Name, field.Value, field.Status);
        }

        valiationMessage = fieldErrors.ToString();

        throw new Exception(valiationMessage);
    }

    tfWorkItem.Save();

    return true;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: How did you set the value using C#? Could you please share the code here for troubleshoot?

Comment: Sample code added in the original question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below C# code sample to set the value of the '`Assigned To`' field, it works on my side: (*You need to specify the `latest revision number` to update the fields. And the value format should be `DOMAIN\\USER`*)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Json;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch;

namespace UpdateFieldValue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myCredentials = new VssClientCredentials();
            var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"), myCredentials);
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            int workitemid = 112;
            JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
            patchDocument.Add(
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Test,
                    Path = "/rev",
                    Value = "6"
                }
            );

            patchDocument.Add(
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
                    Value = "Domain\\user"
                }
            );

            Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.WorkItem result = workItemTrackingClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, workitemid).Result;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Andy, you're code is performing this action using the WebAPI Nuget packages whereas I am using the client object model Nuget packages. I was able to make it work with the WebAPI model as well as making direct REST calls via C#, that's not the issue. The issue is this is not working via the client object model. Thanks.